# Uselessly slow printing pattern for second-to-top layer of Swiss-cheese-like model (using SuperSlicer/PrusaSlicer)

Tags: infill, prusaslicer

I am printing a flat plate that has swiss-cheese like holes in the top layer ONLY, but the layer beneath the swiss-cheese one is uniformly flat.

Desired outcome: second-to-top layer prints clean back-and-forth plus ironing for holes.

Current outcome: second-to-top layer takes almost 10x longer (than the layer before it) to print because it cuts up the back-and-forth of the "Solid Infill" with "Top Solid Infill" circles.

Question: How do I make the second-to-top layer print like the third-to-top layer except with ironing?

Details:
Right now my slicer is seeing the parts of the exposed holes on the second-to-top layer as "Top Solid Infill" (according to the verbose gcode) which makes sense because it is the top-most for that part below the circle hole.

The slicer creates little "Internal Perimeter"s in a space below each hole...
[image: InternalPerimeter]

and then fills them in with "Top Solid Infill"...
[image: TopSolidInfill]

before sporadically filling the rest of the layer with "Solid Infill".
[image: SolidInfill]

It then goes and adds all the ironing for the parts that will be exposed through the holes that will be printed in the layer above.
[image: Ironing]

I'm wondering if I can do something like merge Top Solid Infill with Solid Infill, or maybe disabling Top Solid Infill altogether would work, but I can't find settings for either possibility. Again my question: How do I make the second-to-top layer print like the third-to-top layer except with ironing?

Comment: In Cura this is called Skin Edge Support. Maybe there's a similar thing in PS/SS?

Comment: I'm currently using a workaround but it requires editing the gcode. I do it by adding the part that is the filled holes to the model but putting it on a second extruded (just in the slicer, my printer doesn't actually have two extruders). Then I move the hole-fillers to the last thing to print and delete the last section of the gcode so the print just stops right before filling in the holes. That way in doesn't view the bottom of the holes as top layer and prints it all in the same moevements. It doesn't get ironing on each hole, but since it's imbedded anyway you can't really notice anyway.